# Passing JSON API response to JADE for loop

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

I have a json response that I would like to transform to a `dropdown`. I'm using a jade template to handle the for loop but I'm having troubles getting the values. I'd like the sys_id be passed as a value on selecting the option(u_product_name) from the dropdown.

**Express JS Route**

```
exports.jap = function(req, res){

result = //result is coming from API but this is what a console.log(result) shows
{ result: 
   [ 
     { sys_id: '7d950856',
       u_product_name: 'ACCESS' },
     { sys_id: '803279e1',
       u_product_name: 'AVAYA' },
     { sys_id: '87484c96',
       u_product_name: 'ADAMO' },
     { sys_id: 'b3b9001a',
       u_product_name: 'ADM' } 
   ]
}
res.render('lang', {
    results: result
});
}
```

**lang.jade**

```
select(name='product')
   - each r in results
        option(value="#{r[0]['sys_id']}") #{r.0.u_product_name} //trying a couple different conventions here with no luck.
```

Closest thing i've gotten was using `JSON strigify`, although that split each letter as a new option. I've tried different notations for accessing the JSON but everything seems to result in undefined.

Comment: I think that this iteration:
`- each r in results`
 should be something like that:
`- each r in results.result`

Comment: Thanks that was it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Savabeal

**lang.jade**

```
select(name='product')
    - for r in results.result
        option(value="#{r.sys_id}") #{r.u_product_name}
```